# Validator not firing

Tags: java, jsf, icefaces

I have this component:

```
<ice:form style="width: 45%;" partialSubmit="true" >
    <ice:inputText id="cc" required="true" partialSubmit="true" immediate="true"
        value="#{userAction.username}">
        <f:validator validatorId="passwordValidator" />
        <ice:message style="color: red;" id="ageError" for="cc" />
    </ice:inputText>
</ice:form>
```

I have declared the validator in faces config:

```
<validator>
    <validator-id>passwordValidator</validator-id>
    <validator-class>com.mydomain.seam_icefaces_test.action.PasswordValidator</validator-class>
</validator>
```

And the validator java class:

```
   package com.mydomain.seam_icefaces_test.action;

import javax.faces.component.UIComponent;
import javax.faces.component.UIInput;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.faces.validator.Validator;
import javax.faces.validator.ValidatorException;

    import org.jboss.seam.faces.FacesMessages;

    public class PasswordValidator implements Validator {

        @Override
        public void validate(FacesContext arg0, UIComponent arg1, Object value)
                throws ValidatorException {
            String val = (String) value;

            if (val.length() == 0)
                ((UIInput) arg1).setValid(false);
            FacesMessages.instance().addToControlFromResourceBundle(arg1.getId(),
                    "invalid.password");

        }
    }
```

I do not understand why this is not firing when it looses focus....

Do you have any ideea?

Thanks.

Comment: So you push a submit button, and validation is not firing?

Comment: I do not push anything...partialSubmit and immediate attribute of the inputText component know to do a POST automatically...

Comment: Is it a typo or you really wrote `immediat` instead of ` immediate` ?

Comment: sorry, it's wrong here but correct within the program.

Comment: Just to test if the validator is correct, add a <h:commandButton> and see if the validator is firing

Answer (score 1):

JSF validators are called during validation fase. They are not called just when control lost the focus. See the [lifecycle](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-jsf3/).

Comment: Yes but I put immediate=true (Using the immediate attribute on a component means its value will be validated during the apply request values phase in the JSF lifecycle. ) and still not firing.

Answer (score 0):

A few things... Shouldn't the last part of your code be like

```
if (val.length() == 0)
{
    ((UIInput) arg1).setValid(false);
    FacesMessages.instance().addToControlFromResourceBundle(arg1.getId(),
                    "invalid.password");
}
```

? This might be why your message is not showing up.

Secondly, the `Immediate` attribute is not necessary. You can try working without it.

Lastly, try using the  `validator="#{MyBean.validatePassword}"` attribute in the `<ice:inputText>` tag, where `validatePassword` is a copy of the `validate` method from the PasswordValidator class.